# What is the origin of the Black Tablet thing surrounded by apes?

Tags: reference, the-simpsons, charlie-and-the-chocolate-factory

In the Tim Burton adaptation *Charlie and the Chocolate Factory* film and one of the episodes of *The Simpsons* both show a scene were a bunch of apes in what seems to be a canyon region are looking at a long black tablet....thing.

- In *Charlie and the Chocolate Factory* it turns into the Wonka Bar that Wonka beamed into the TV
- In *The Simpsons* the apes who used it began to use tools while the Homer Ape touched it and then began to use it as a back scratcher

I am wondering what is the origin of this reference?

Comment: It was also parodied in Mel Brooks' "History of the World, Part I".

Comment: Zoolander had a really funny take on it too.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolith_%28Space_Odyssey%29

Comment: In the original film? You mean the Tim Burton adaptation? Because the original Willy Wonka has no such scene

Comment: @BlueMoon93 ahh yes you're right. corrected

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a reference to the opening scene of the 1968 film [*2001: A Space Odyssey*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_(film)) in which an alien monolith appears among a group of ancient apes and imbues them with the beginnings of human intelligence while [*Thus Spake Zarathustra*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Also_sprach_Zarathustra_(Strauss)) plays.

Here is a clip on YouTube:

Comment: If you've only ever seen the parody, it might be difficult to watch this with a straight face https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y15NnGZIBuM (like watching Zero Hour! *after* having seen Airplane!)

Comment: Many said that the monolyth represents extraterrestrial intelligence, and how its present through all human history. Some others say that is the representation of a cinema screen into the "real world" of the film. The idea of "monkeys in front of something they cant understand" is also quoted in Zoolander (2001) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ze3hthGRbRo